# android webView zoom in out problems

Tags: android

I am developing an app and there is `webview` tab, on it i give zoom in out from `.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);`. However when i zoom out (the view gets smaller and smaller until minus button(zoom out)disabled itself)the `webview` showing white background that i don't even set a background on the layout. how to make `webview` on zoom out have some resolution which will fit the height of the screen?  and I am curious if we can make the zoom controls always seen?(it only appear whenever we touch the screen and make some move on it(tap, hold and move))

here is my java code from webview

```
public class WebViewActivity extends Activity {
    private WebView webView;
    //private static final FrameLayout.LayoutParams ZOOM_PARAMS = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,Gravity.BOTTOM);

      @Override
    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.webview);
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true); 
        webView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
        webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
        webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()); 
        webView.loadUrl("http://www.somewebsitename.com");
      }
}
```

and here is my xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<WebView  
    android:id="@+id/webView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</WebView>
</LinearLayout>
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
webView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(true);
```

Comment: webView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(true);  doesnt work with api lower than 11. I am using api 8

Comment: yes,when the api lower than 11, setDisplayZoomControls(true)doesnt work and unfortunately，it looks like there is no alternative